# Monitoring Windows Hard Drives

Tags: windows, monitoring, hard-drive, diskmanagement

When you run several 100 windows servers and even business systems, what is a good option for monitoring hard disks and checking for bad sectors?

Are there applications out there that can send e-mail reports with enough information to know what computer or server is having the issues?

Answer (score 4):

With that many servers, you should already have some sort of centralized monitoring solution already in place. You should investigate that solution supporting your server vendor's monitoring interface, i.e. HP Insight, Dell OpenManage, etc., because that will yield the most reliable and most useful information.